# Swift: How to make bullet spawn at player weapon?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a class CharacterCreator which makes the player and inside it I have these functions to make the player shoot:

```
func shoot(scene: SKScene) {
    if (playerArmed) {
        let bullet = self.createBullet()
        scene.addChild(bullet)
        bullet.position = playerWeaponBarrel.position
        bullet.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(200, 0)
    }
}

func createBullet() -> SKShapeNode {
    let bullet = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 2)
    bullet.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bullet.frame.height / 2)
    bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bullet
    bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ground
    bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ground
    return bullet
}
```

The `playerWeaponBarrel` child node is where the bullet should spawn. What happens is that when I call the shoot() function at GameScene:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if (touchedNode == fireButton) {
            Player.shoot(self.scene!)
        }
```

it just won't create the bullet at the playerWeaponBarrel. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `playerWeaponBarrel.position` is relative to its super node, which is probably the `player`. But you want the `bullet` to be located absolutely in the scene, not relative to the `player`. Therefore what you need to do is convert the `playerWeaponBarrel.position` from its local coordinate system to the `scene` coordinate system:

```
bullet.position = scene.convertPoint(playerWeaponBarrel.position, fromNode: playerWeaponBarrel.parent!)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was doing this just right now! Thank you for your answer :)